# how can I send to javascript console in browser code entered by user in textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I want to build a webpage for user to be able to practice code exercises. in javascript. and I'm looking for a way to execute the code on the browser session and display the user if there's any errors. I was wondering if by grabbing user text from textarea and executing it as part of a function will work. Here's what I got, but I haven't been able to send to console the user entered text.. any help thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JScript Page</title>
    <script>
      function jstest() {
        var text = document.getElementById("textArea").value;
        console.log(text);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Enter your code here!</h2>
    <form  >
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="textArea">
</textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="jstest()">
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `eval()` to execute the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is that the form is being submitted and it makes the page to refresh and that's why you can't see the `console.log`. You can `return false` to prevent the form submission or remove the `form` at all.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JScript Page</title>
  <script>
    function jstest() {
      var text = document.getElementById("textArea").value;
      console.log(text);
      return false;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Enter your code here!</h2>
  <form>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="textArea">
</textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return jstest();">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**WITHOUT FORM (AND EVAL)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JScript Page</title>
  <script>
    function jstest() {
      var text = document.getElementById("textArea").value;
      try {
        eval(text);
      } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof SyntaxError) {
          alert(e.message);
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Enter your code here!</h2>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="textArea">alert('some')</textarea><br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="jstest();">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: One suggestion I would make is in your "without Form" example, don't use a submit button at all. To make it more semantic, use the button HTML element (or input type="button" if you need IE <10 support).

Comment: thank you very much... but why I try your example on my page and I don't get the code to run?.. if I enter 1 + 1, I get 2 on console.log which is a huge improvement. Another question is: why it will not give me errors when omitting semicolon at the end of a statement. That would be great since it will provide me with sintax error checking... thanks you

Comment: never mind about code not executing, I guess I needed to refresh the page. I just need the second portion of the question. Can I get syntax correction? I don't get displayed any error to console if I miss a semicolon

Comment: Semicolon at the end of a statement is not required in JavaScript, that is why you don't see any errors.

Comment: ok.. when I type a syntax error like: var = 1; console.log(var + i); the console displays something but it refresh it and I don't get to see the kind of error. Is there any way to capture the sysntax error in javascript console? Thanks

Comment: you can use a `try/catch`, I added it to the answer